# Sending a SELECT sql variable array from one file to another in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to module.export "rows" from this function over to anotherfile.js

**"mysql.js"**

```
const gameserverShow = function () {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM gameservers`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        return rows;
    });
 }

module.exports.gameserverShow = gameserverShow;
```

I  tried to make a "foreach loop" into a array and send it over, but everytime I try to console.log it, it return "undefined". is there a different/correct way to do it?

**"anotherfile.js"**

```
const mysqlcon = require("./mysql.js");
      if (args[0] == 'show') {
            mysqlcon.gameserverShow();
            console.log(mysqlcon.gameserverShow.rows);
      }
```

Comment: this doesn't work this way.. which version of nodejs you are using?

Comment: This is a very basic thing in javascript and it's async nature, so you should first understand that. though answering this question which is not very encouraged on the stack.

Comment: Well I'm a learner and I'm using the newest recommended version of nodejs. I know its not encouraged to answer question on the stack, I try to avoid being here and find the answer myself. But I hit a wall and I couldn't get over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing that in a wrong way. You should first read how javascript function calls, callbacks works and how to handle async tasks in javascript. You have to handle it asynchronously with callbacks or promise. As you are using callbacks here following is basic code for that.

```
const gameserverShow = function (callback) {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM gameservers`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        callback(null, rows);
    });
 }

module.exports.gameserverShow = gameserverShow;
```

And in Another file

```
const mysqlcon = require("./mysql.js");
      if (args[0] == 'show') {
            mysqlcon.gameserverShow((error, rows) => {
               console.log(rows);
            });
      }
```

You can search how to do that with promises. There are many questions about that here.